# Finding closest possible coordinates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, collision, nearest-neighbor

I have x,y coordinates board like this:

[image]

the board is up to 100x100.

Where **myPosition** is gold, **destinations** is green and **collisions** is red. `myPosition` is object `destinations` and `collisions` are array of objects:

```
let myPosition={x:0,y:0};
let destinations = [{x: 0, y: 5}, {x: 2, y: 0}, {x: 2, y: 2}];
let collisions = [{x: 1, y: 0},{x: 1, y: 1},{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 1, y: 3},{x: 1, y: 4},{x: 2, y: 1},{x: 2, y: 0},{x: 2, y: 1}]
```

With [this code (live demo)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXRPXZ?editors=0010) I'm able to find nearest destination but it doesn't know about collisions at all. I can not figure how to write algorithm which additionally would check for collision and give ouput `0,5` in above scenerio.

There is also assumption that we can not move diagonally.

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748986/how-to-check-if-a-possible-path-exist) which seems to provide answer to my question but I can not get it to work with my input arrays.

Comment: This sounds to me like you're looking for a pathing solution, the first that comes to mind is a-star ( a* )

see: http://buildnewgames.com/astar/ .

a* is also mentioned in the SO answer you referenced

Comment: even your current solution is wrong as it calculates squared distance so it allows diagonal moves. You want to do something like bfs

Comment: I found A* library but in usage https://github.com/prettymuchbryce/easystarjs#usage there is grid with 0 and 1 where I believe 0 is walkable and 1 is not. Can I somehow convert my object/arrays to grid like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [pathFinding.js](https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js) library and finding is very simple:

```
currentPath = finder.findPath(heroCoords.x, 
                              heroCoords.y, 
                              monstersCoords[i].x, 
                              monstersCoords[i].y,
                              currentGrid);
```